# Why does Tkinter's submenu show on left side in python?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, menu, submenu

I ran into an issue with Tkinter, here's what the issue visually looks like:

[image: Example #1]

Where as I'd like the menu box to stay within my window on the right, like so:

[image: Example #2]

Here's the code I'm using as well:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog

def savepasswords():
    name=tkFileDialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w',defaultextension=".txt")
    name.write("test document")
    name.close

root = Tk()
menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
filemenu = Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
submenu = Menu(filemenu, tearoff=0)
menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
filemenu.add_cascade(label="Save", menu=submenu)
submenu.add_command(label="Save passwords", command = savepasswords)

root.mainloop()
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: It's alright on my win 7 64bit. I guess it's probably there's not enough room for the menu to fully show up on the right side in your desktop, maybe?

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce what you're getting either.

Comment: Even when I make the window bigger it still shows on the left side. It will only show on the right side when I drag the window all the way to the left side of my screen.

Comment: It appears it could just be my computer, I'll leave this up for a little bit in case someone says otherwise.

Comment: I tried it on linux, and I can't repoduce the problem either.

Comment: Your script works on my Linux 16.04 using Python 2.7.12.